# Access sessionStorage at componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I was under the assumption that `sessionStorage` gets instantiated after a component has been mounted and one can access it through a `componentDidMount` call.

I am using [this script](https://gist.github.com/afrozek/6ff028acee797a194adbd2d371644046) to preserve my `sessionStorage` through different tabs:

```
(function() {     
  if (!sessionStorage.length) {
    // Ask other tabs for session storage
    localStorage.setItem('getSessionStorage', Date.now());
  };

  window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
    if (event.key == 'getSessionStorage') {
      // Some tab asked for the sessionStorage -> send it
      localStorage.setItem('sessionStorage', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
      localStorage.removeItem('sessionStorage');
    } else if (event.key == 'sessionStorage' && !sessionStorage.length) {
      // sessionStorage is empty -> fill it
      let data = JSON.parse(event.newValue);
      for (key in data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);
      }
      showSessionStorage();
    }
});

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //sessionStorage.clear();
  };
})();
```

which seems to work as intended.

I am trying to access my `sessionStorage` through the `componentDidMount` method of the following (stripped down) component:

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('someData'));
  }
```

The above works as intended on the same tab.

When I open a new tab though, on the console I get `null` from the `sessionStorage`.
If I refresh the new tab, I get the correct `someData` value printed.

**EDIT:**

I did change my implementation to use a cookie in order to achieve my needs, but I am still interested in the problem and any potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended.

Session storage works for your current session. When you open a new tab you are creating a new session, that's why the initial data is null.

Use localStorage to persist data within tabs.

I don't know your use case but start with switching out sessionStorage and localStorage.

Save the normal things on `sessionStorage`. 
Persist on `localStorage`

Comment: I understand. Maybe the react component is accessing sessionStorage before the script has finished running. Try implementing a setTimout of 1-5 seconds and see if it works.

Comment: What you suggest works but has 2 major problems:
1) It is probabilistic (it may work but it may not work as well)
2) It adds loading time which I do not want.

Comment: That's just to see if that was the problem. setTimouts are actually a bad practice. You can now fix this with a Promise. Create it with new Promise(). Resolve it at the end of the code. Now on your react component do await (if using async/babel) window.sessionStorage..., otherwise just use a plain promise .then(data => console.log(data))