# React - Redirect user to login if not logged otherwise go forward

Tags: reactjs, redirect, authentication, react-router

Start component `App` renders `Wellcome` component, which further renders `Login` component.

These are routes from `Router`:

```
   <Route exact path={"/welcome"} component={App} />
   <Route exact path={"/"} component={Dashboard} />
```

In `Dashboard` component, I have this check:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('token_object')) {
        this.props.history.push('/welcome');
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Sidebar />
            <div id="content">
                <Navbar />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost:myPort/` in address bar, it should try to render Dashboard component and fail, due to "`if (!sessionStorage.getItem('token_object')) {`" assuming that user is not logged in. But it fails, it just sets URL in browser to `http://localhost:myPort/welcome` but continues to render `Dashboard` component and fails. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There are some other ways to have those checks, like "higher order components" or other tricks. But let's focus on the above example and refactor it a

```
render() {
    const isLogged = !!sessionStorage.getItem('token_object'));

    if (!isLogged) {
        return (
            <Redirect to="/welcome" />
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Sidebar />
            <div id="content">
                <Navbar />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

notes:

- `!!` is for getting a boolean value if token is set or not
- returning the `Redirect` component from redux-router-dom if user is not logged

Answer (score 0):

Here you simply update de address bar of the browser here without using React-router's logic to render the components the way you want.

You could use the `<Redirect />` component of react-router to achieve your goal.

Here's one possible solution assuming the `Dashboard` component is mounted inside a `Router` component:

```
render() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('token_object')) {
        return <Redirect to={'/welcome'} />;
    }
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Sidebar />
            <div id="content">
                <Navbar />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to log sessionStorage value and even window.sessionStorage.

**Remember that normally sessionStorage would be available on componentDidMount.**

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996854/access-sessionstorage-at-componentdidmount) to better clarify how sessionStorage works.

**Remember that sessionStorage is not available with server-side rendering.**

Answer (score 0):

You must use conditional rendering.

See this example by reactjs.org:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // Try changing to isLoggedIn={true}:
  <Greeting isLoggedIn={false} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```